# Older JAX-WS don't create whole package

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I'm a Java beginner, but I don't have any experience with JAX-WS, JAXB, XJC etc, and I have some ant script which are marshaling and compiling my java classes via JAX-WS. Earlier it running under JDK 6 and perform `<exec>` ant task to fork wsimport process to generate and compile java classes. Now I should run it under both JDK 6 and JDK 8 (which have different included JAX* versions!) so I going to run wsimport via `<taskdef>` tag and use my own JAX-WS library to be independent from JDK version.

In JDK 6 was included `JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6` and `JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6` libs, but now I going to use `JAX-WS 2.1.3` and `JAXB 2.1.6` (don't ask me, why I choose older library:) ).

So my issue is: when I using wsimport from JDK 6 I have `abc._2003._07` and `abc._2011._10` packages on output, but when I start to use older libs I get only the first one.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a good answer if you provide example code so that others can reproduce your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved by adding jaxb:version="anyVersion" attribute in .xsd's root tag. Apparently in previous JAXB version this attribute is required.